# React Navigation showing selected screen in contentComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to change the background of the selected screen item to highlight that it is active. Currently, this code works as expected:

[image: Screenshot showing map selected]

However, when you select another screen it wrongly shows both of them highlighted.

[image]

I am struggling to understand why this is. I am comparing what I understand as the active screen index against the index number of the screen.

I would be very grateful if anyone could provide advice on how to fix this!

**Individual menu item:**

```
class MenuItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingHorizontal: 16, backgroundColor: this.props.active && COLOURS[1] || '' }}>
        <View style={{ width: 32, justifyContent: 'center' }}><Icon color="#7ba6d5" size={24} type={this.props.config.iconType} name={this.props.config.iconName} /></View>
        <LinearTextGradient
          style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Comfortaa-Bold', paddingVertical: 16, marginLeft: 8 }}
          locations={[0, 0.5, 1]}
          colors={['#7ba6d5', '#7ba6d5', '#7ba6d5']}
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}>

          { this.props.config.label }
        </LinearTextGradient>
        { this.props.badge && <Badge /> }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Side Menu (contentComponent):**

```
class SideMenu extends Component {
  render () {
    const config = {
      Map: { label: 'Map', iconName: 'map', iconType: 'material' },
      Setup: { label: 'Setup', iconName: 'settings', iconType: 'material' },
      Win: { label: 'Win an iPad', iconName: 'gift', iconType: 'font-awesome' },
      Help: { label: 'Help', iconName: 'help-with-circle', iconType: 'entypo' }
    };

    return (
      <LinearGradient colors={[COLOURS[1], COLOURS[0]]} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.menuImage}><Image source={require('./img/rygo-large.png')} style={{width: '65%'}} resizeMode="contain" /></View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Map')}><MenuItem active={this.props.navigation.state.index == 1} config={config['Map']} /></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Setup')}><MenuItem active={this.props.navigation.state.index == 2} config={config['Setup']} /></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Win')}><MenuItem active={this.props.navigation.state.index == 3} config={config['Win']} /></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Help')}><MenuItem active={this.props.navigation.state.index == 4} config={config['Help']} /></TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.menuFooterText}>Version {APP_VERSION}</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
}
```

**Drawer Navigator config:**

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Launch: LaunchScreen,
  Map: MapStack,
  Setup: SetupStack,
  Win: WinScreen,
  Help: HelpScreen,
}, {
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `DrawerItems` component.

Comment: @Li357 I needed more customisation and `getLabel` didn't provide me with enough freedom to achieve what I was looking to do

Comment: Hello ... I am having the same issue with my app have you manage to find a solution to this ?